# "Вирішувати", "ухвалювати рішення", or "приймати рішення"?

Tags: вибір-слова, різниця-між-словами

I understand it this way:

[Вирішувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyrishuvaty) - the most common term valid for almost any situation.

[Ухвалювати рішення](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukhvaljuvaty) - used in the official language to describe the decision made by some authority.

[Приймати рішення](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieslovo-prujmatu-pravula-vzhuvannya) isn't tolerated much by hardcore linguists but [widely used](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%80%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22&*) by general public. Should we consider it russianism or forget about the Russian influence in this case?

Comment: So, the question is, in what situation should one use which word, correct? (it is not very clearly stated)

Comment: @bytebuster it's 1. Which one to use in which situation? 2. Juxtaposition of the first two of them and the last one. If there is such. 
Therefore, the main question is "where to use each of them?", and the complementary question is "should I use the last one at all if I want to speak proper Ukrainian?"

Comment: See also: [«УХВАЛИТИ ЧИ ПРИЙНЯТИ ЗАКОН?»](/q/4309) (Ukr.).

Comment: @Sasha я наче вже розібрався, що там всі ці варіанти в різних випадках можна використовувати, але руки не доходять зробити хорошу відповідь.

Answer (score 3):

Відповідно до інформації на сайті [Мова ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieslovo-prujmatu-pravula-vzhuvannya) можна вживати як "вирішувати", так і "ухвалювати рішення". А от "приймати рішення" - це калька з російської. Про це йдеться і в статті "Мовні порушення" на сайті  [Народний Оглядач](https://www.ar25.org/article/movni-porushennya-zi-slovamy-pryymaty-pryyty-ta-yih-zamina.html), на сайті [Ресурсно-методичного центру](http://www.rmc-ltl.info/kalka-surzhyk-smittya-movne/) (там же пропонують варіант "виносити ухвалу"),

Однак, наприклад, в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjmaty) пише, що варіант "приймати рішення" - можливий. Та й на багатьох сайтах в Інтернеті я зустрічав такий варіант (хоч, вони і не є офіційними джерелами). І ще я натрапив на слова [проф. Пономарева](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-41932102) про "прийняти закон" і "ухвалити закон" (розумію, що ситуація тут трішки інша, але все ж), де він каже, що обидва варіанти можливі, але варто надавати перевагу другому.

Отож, варто надавати перевагу словам “вирішувати” та “ухвалювати рішення”, але і варіант "приймати рішення" також можливий.